# Cycle between multiple images

Tags: jquery, html

I have this problem: I would like to change the `src` attribute of an `img` element in a continuous loop.

Here is my HTML and jQuery code:

```
<img id="changeSlider" src="{{asset('uploads/photos/')}}{{photo.path}}" alt="">
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var i = 1;
    while(i < 10) {
        $("#changeSlider").attr('src', '{{asset("uploads/photos/")}}{{photos[0].path}}').delay(3000);
        i++;
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean forever?

Comment: Do you mean you want to repeatedly cycle between a set of images? What is the `photos` variable?

Comment: yes i mean repeatedly ... photos is array with 5-25 objects of entity photo, photo.path is path to photography

Comment: You cannot have a while loop. You need to use setTimeout or use the onload. Also your JavaScript does not attempt to change anything

Comment: Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5010883/simple-jquery-photo-slideshow

Comment: better idea i will try it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can update the image path on a regular timebase by setIntervall and cycle through the images (assuming a function that can generate the image url based on the index):

```
var count = 20; // actual number of available photos
var next = 0;

window.setInterval(showNextImage, 3000);

function showNextImage() {
 $('#changeSlider').prop('src', URL_OF_PHOTO(next));
 next = (++next)%count;
}
```